# Not able to change fragment after clicking on recyclerview items

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView in my Main Activity. I want to change different fragments after clicking on different recyclerview Items. I try this by using position from onbindviewholder() but i am not able to change the fragment when i click on recyclerview items. I am not getting any error but at the same time nothing is happening onclick of recyclerview. Please check my code and tell me where i am wrong or which line of code i am missing.

RecyclerAdapter Code:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<NewModel> newModels;
Context context;
public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<NewModel>newModels, Context context){
    this.newModels = newModels;
    this.context = context;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recy_layout, parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(newModels.get(position).getImg());
    holder.textView.setText(newModels.get(position).getText());
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(position ==1){
                ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.framelayout, new FirstFragment());
            }
            else if(position ==2){
                ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.framelayout, new SecondFragment());
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newModels.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cirlceimg);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you forgot to call commit()**

do this:

```
(((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.framelayout, new SecondFragment()).commit();
```

Fragment is not rendered until you call commit() on the transaction , because transaction use builder pattern and in builder pattern there is a method to say that i don't want to do anything else just create the object, normally these method are name **create()** , **build()**, and **commit()** in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `onClickListener` from your activity using callback implementation with an interface.

**Interface:**

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

Add the listener to your adapter's constructor

```
ArrayList<NewModel> newModels;
Context context;
private final OnItemClickListener listener;

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<NewModel>newModels, Context context, OnItemClickListener listener){
    this.newModels = newModels;
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

In your `onBindViewHolder` set the clicklistener

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(newModels.get(position).getImg());
    holder.textView.setText(newModels.get(position).getText());
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           listener.onItemClick(position);
        }
    });

}
```

In your activity:

```
RecyclerAdapter rvAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(newModels, this, new RecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override public void onItemClick(int item) {
            if(position ==1){
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, new FirstFragment()).commit();;}
            else if(position ==2){
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, new SecondFragment()).commit();;
                    }
            }});
recycler.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside **onBindViewHolder**

```
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(position ==1){
                ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.framelayout, new FirstFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            else if(position ==2){
            ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.framelayout, new SecondFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Hope this helps you.